# Datatable Json with Special Character like (",') are not accepted. "showing missing )" error

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-core

I am building JSON from C#.We getting the Json from C# View model and We initialize that Json into string as below

```
var jsondataObject = eval('@Html.Raw(Model.Datasource)');
```

Json will look like below and added with single and double quotes

```
  var jsondataObject = eval('[{"COLUMNS":[{"title":"Button", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"testName", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"test Start Date", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"Test End Date", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"Pack Number", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"Pack", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"test Type(UOM)", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"Test Rate", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"Created Date", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"Created By", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"Modified Date", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" },{"title":"Modified By", "visible" :"False", "width" :"100" }],"DATA":[["20","test10","07/07/2020","07/07/2020","27488"," Corrections","  Percentage","","07/07/2020","   Saikrishnan","07/07/2020","saikrishnan"],["21","test89","07/07/2020","07/09/2020","27488"," Corrections","  Percentage","","07/07/2020","   Saikrishnan","07/07/2020","Saikrishnan"],["22","xzxzfc","","","","","","","07/07/2020","Saikrishnan","07/07/2020","Saikrishnan"],["23",**"test>><?{_)'"**(*&","","","","","","","07/07/2020","Saikrishnan","07/07/2020","Saikrishnan"],["24","test","","","","","","","07/07/2020","Saikrishnan","07/07/2020","Saikrishnan"]]}]');
```

When we don't have any single or double Quotes it is working fine.But when we have single or double quotes,it is throwing error and table is not entering.Since know why this is happening.But can any one tell me how to handle this Please

```
$('#testTl').DataTable({
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "data": dataObject[0].DATA,
    "columns": dataObject[0].COLUMNS
})
```

Comment: Try if it works without the (**[evil](http://linterrors.com/js/eval-is-evil)**) eval: `var jsondataObject = @Html.Raw(Model.Datasource);`

Comment: if i remove the eval it saying "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

Comment: can anyone give any suggestion, please

Comment: There is no `length` being used in any of the code that you are showing, you need to add that code.

Comment: I removed eval.it is working fine without single and double-quotes . But now also it is not accepting the single quotes and double quotes do we have a method to accept this double and single quotes in the string please

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you have control over the data, try using escape string.

Ex: `var temp = data.replace(/"/g, "\\\"") and temp.replace(/'/g, "\\'")`

Comment: hi.Thanks for the answer.But That is my requirement.Json should also accept Single and double quotes in the string,Can anyone give some suggestion on that please

Comment: Hey, try escape string. It might help. For example: 'That\'s ' will print That's.